# Removing JavaFx libs to make JavaFx.jar file load faster

Tags: installation, javafx, java

I have created a JavaFx application, however when i try to open it on a shared harddrive in my office the loading time is extreamly slow.

Me and my co-worker have tried to figure out what the problem might be and found that it might be because the file is to big because of the JavaFx lib. According to [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html)

> As of JavaFX 2.2 and Java SE 7 update 6, the JavaFX libraries are installed as part of Java SE; a standalone version of JavaFX 2.2 will remain available for Java SE 6 users (Windows only) until Java SE 6 reaches End-of-Life in February 2013.

With that in mind shouldnt i be able to remove the JavaFx lib from the application without risking that the application wont work? or is there another solution to my problem?

One important thing to note is that when i run the file locally from my desktop there is no problem at all and the program loads within 3 sec.

Answer (score 0):

What that article is saying is that the Java 7 JRE now includes the JavaFX runtime.  There isn't some special library that's bundled with your application that you can just eliminate.

If you're bundling the JRE with your application (using the  ant task, or the JavaFX Packager Tool) then it's possible your application is using the JRE on the shared drive, which could cause the slowdown.  More info on this is available: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm

Otherwise, your problem lies elsewhere.  Areas of concern would be:

1. Network speed
2. Shared drive speed
3. Excessive classpath scanning

Comment: so what your saying is that if that server the shared drive runs from does not have java 7 it will have a harder time loading?

Comment: No.  If you're bundling the JRE with your application - and your application is being run from a shared drive - then it will use the JRE on the shared drive.  That would be a big performance hit.  If you're generating an .EXE file or you see a RUNTIME folder, then this is probably the case.  If you're not bundling the JRE with your application, then it's using the JRE on your local machine, and that's  not the problem.